# forward the domain and remove the port number from the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

With this. **.htaccess code**, the domain is forwarded to port 8000. The problem is the port number in the URL.

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.subdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my.subdomain.com:8000/$1 [R=301]
```

I am now looking for a way to forward the domain and remove the port number from the URL. There must be a solution with PHP or. **.htaccess** be. Web server and all of my domains are running on port 80 and on port number 8000 is running an application.

Edit and modify the httpd.conf file does not work. It is Overridden again. :-( My Hoster confirmed me that

Thank you!

Comment: If you're webserver is running on the port 8000, then that redirect won't work. If I type my.subdomain.com in my browser, then my browser will try to connect on the port 80.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you give example input URLs and output URLs?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. are you trying to internally rewrite it to port 8000 instead of 80 because you are currently redirecting it

Comment: Web server and all of my domains are running on port 80

Comment: Please edit your question and explain exactly what you are trying to do. if your webserver and all domains are on port 80 then I do not understand why the port 8000 or what you are trying to do

Comment: I do not understand what is now unclear? FORWARD the domain and REMOVE the port number from the URL.

On port number 8000 is running an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxypass imperatives are available in Apache as well as ngnix. I recently answered a different question with the same solution to your problem here: https://serverfault.com/q/448733/261031 and on my own website here: http://joshwieder.blogspot.com/2014/12/apache-virtualhost-proxy-config-nodejs-tomcat.html but I will also reproduce the example here with the port numbers you have specified:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.subdomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset Off
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://my.subdomain.com:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://my.subdomain.com:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that with this configuration you will be able to access your site both with and without port number 8000 as a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Try Nginx server its quit easy!

bellow is its demo config.

```
server {
listen       80;  
server_name  blog.ramki.com;  
rewrite_log  on;
error_log    logs/error_ramki.log   notice;
rewrite   ^/(.*)$   /department1/$1;   
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8282;  
}
}
```

for further reference please visit [This](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/virtual-host-nginx-tomcat.html)

Comment: Okay. but I will not because of a port number in the URL, my server (Apache) changed to Nginx. :-)

Comment: My result (also for all others). It does not work. 
Apache server, port forwarding and port number. with .htaccess or PHP Remove.